# Move and apply modifier on a linked object

Tags: modifiers, linked-data, asset-browser

I have a master file where I have my objects and materials. I want to be able to use them in other files I shall be able to move and apply array modifiers on them.

When I make changes to the master file, the changes shall be reflected in all the files where I used the asset.

When I drag the object from the asset browser with the link method, I am not able to move the asset and apply the array modifier on the object.

I want to be able to move and apply array modifiers on the linked object, how can I do this ?

[image: Asset Browser]